# How to insert output data from the javascript inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I a beginner trying to learn javascript. I successfully filter the the json and get output in console log(). But how to print the output inside a div using innerHtml.

```
<script>fetch("workers.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) =>
  console.log(
    json.filter(function (item) {
      return item.name == "sam";
    })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to choose HTML-node to paste in your content.
like this:
`const myNode = document.querySelector('.my-class')`
after that you need simply to paste your content inside, like:
`myNode.textContent = myContent`

Comment: can you please give the full working js. I'm still struggling to get the output

Comment: that's no problem to make full working js, but i don't know your details, like what html node you want to paste in, your response structure, et.c

Comment: it is just for educational purpose, so no worry. just code in your own style all i need is to understand how its work

Comment: here is my working example. https://jsfiddle.net/zd6Lbteo/2/

Comment: please, also mark my answer as correct if it helps you

Comment: this is what i'm excepting but  can use phrase the js using filter using user id: 1 instead of using (stringify)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234641/discussion-between-99-tools-and-paul-zaslavskij).